# Python PPTX module Installation Issue

Tags: python-pptx

I have locally installed python-pptx and extract pptx file from this package.

Package Installed in local Drive : python-pptx-0.6.18.tar.gz

OS Version : windows 10.0

Python Version : 3.3.0

while im trying to import pptx file. It showing error no module lxml found.

Could someone please let me know how to fix this issue and why its arising.

Thanks for your support in advance

Comment: Can you provide the actual error log? But by what you are saying you are missing a library https://pypi.org/project/lxml/, just install it with `pip install lxml`

Answer (score 0):

As @simkusr noted in a comment, it does sound like you're just missing a library. Try:

```
pip install lxml
```